# Why am I getting "trusty" in a path while running ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, kernel, dmesg

I'm running ubuntu 12.04 and on a different partition there is a ubuntu 14.04 distribution.

When running `dmesg` one entry is the following:

> [ 3161.519138] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 4782 at /build/buildd/linux-lts-trusty-3.13.0/drivers/media/v4l2-core/v4l2-dev.c:779 __video_register_device+0x452/0x540 videodev

How come I have a **`trusty`** (ie ubuntu 14.04 codename) in the path of this: `linux-lts-trusty-3.13.0`?

Does this mean I'm somehow not running 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you are running 12.04.5 and it is the [hardware enablement stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/1204_HWE_EOL#What_to_do_if_I.27m_affected.3F) that was introduced a few months ago. Some relevant parts from the link:

> **What is HWE?**
>
> Hardware Enablement Stacks (HWE) are incorporated into installers for select Ubuntu LTS (Long Term Support) point releases. It is a special Ubuntu feature that provides an LTS release with hardware support introduced in newer Ubuntu releases. For Ubuntu 12.04 the point releases are .2/.3/.4/.5 and the corresponding Ubuntu releases are 12.10/13.04/13.10/14.04.
>
> The HWE path can be obtained in 2 ways:
>
> - Installing Ubuntu from the media (ISO) for these point releases (where HWE is used by default)
> - Manually installing some packages
>
> End-of-life (EOL) for 12.04, 12.04.1, and 12.04.5 HWE is April 2017 but for the other HWE stacks it is roughly when 14.04.1 is released: Aug 8, 2014.
>
> **And why should I care?***
>
> Starting Aug 8, 2014 systems running 12.04.2 HWE, 12.04.3 HWE, or 12.04.4 HWE will no longer receive software updates for the kernel and, if you're running it, the graphics stack.

Comment: do you know where I can find the 12.04.1 installation?

Comment: also is there a difference between 12.04 and 12.04.1?

Comment: found it here I think http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.1/ubuntu-12.04.1-desktop-i386.iso